# Dashing EC2 Widget Throwing Backport error with AWS-SDK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dashing

I have a Dashing dashboard and would like to use the Dashing EC2 Cloudfront widget within it.  The gist for the widget is here https://gist.github.com/jwalton/6614087 and Dashing is here http://shopify.github.io/dashing/#widgets

I have RVM manage my ruby and gems and have the aws-sdk gem as well as all other gems installed.

The #lib/dashing_ec2.rb file is causing the error with the require aws-sdk

I am unsure what to do from here as I researched Backports and found nothing relatable.

This is the error from thin.log of Dashing:

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/backports-3.6.0/lib/backports/tools.rb:343:in `require': cannot load such file -- aws-sdk (LoadError)
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/backports-3.6.0/lib/backports/tools.rb:343:in `require_with_backports'
    from /opt/opsdash/lib/dashing_ec2.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/backports-3.6.0/lib/backports/tools.rb:343:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/backports-3.6.0/lib/backports/tools.rb:343:in `require_with_backports'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/dashing-1.3.2/lib/dashing.rb:162:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/dashing-1.3.2/lib/dashing.rb:162:in `each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/dashing-1.3.2/lib/dashing.rb:162:in `<top (required)>'
    from config.ru:1:in `require'
    from config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:1:in `new'
    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:182:in `load_rackup_config'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:72:in `start'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:199:in `run_command'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:155:in `run!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/gems/thin-1.6.2/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/bin/thin:23:in `load'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@dashing/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do you have the `aws-sdk` gem installed?

Comment: Yes, it is in my gemset and I am using that gemset.  When I do a gem list,I see it.

Comment: Are you using bundler? is it in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

It was in my gemset, but not in my Gemfile.

Adding to Gemfile resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

add to Gemfile(and bundle install ) : 
    gem 'aws-sdk'

you need to change the '**lib_dashing_ec2.rb**'(from the gist) under "**lib/dashing_ec2.rb**"
and change the require in the ec2.rb file: 
require '**./lib/dashing_ec2'**